# AngularJs watch for change in variable inside a service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have a `service` named `loginManager` which stores objects called `is_logged_in` & `api_token` along with few others. My various controllers make ajax calls using $http using the api_token.

> If the api_token is reset/expired on server, response is sent as `auth_error`, at this point I set `is_logged_in = false`

What i want to achieve is, whenever `is_logged_in` is changed, the service redirects to `/login` using `$location.path('/login')`, i.e. to say, *I want to **watch** the object inside the service, and invoke callback on change from service itself*.

I just want the service to take care of login and corresponding routing, without any controller worrying about weather user is logged in or not.

Comment: why don't you "listen" upon 401 errors (authorization errors) and redirect in case of any 401 is thrown?

Comment: If you already have the logic to detect auth errors, and already set is_logged_in to false, then you just need to call $location.path('/login') at the same time. What is the problem exactly? Why would you need a watch?

Comment: the server responds json data and also, i'm more concerned about the login validation rather than authorization errors

Comment: You can not use $watch in any service because it can not have access to scope.

Comment: @JBNizet the problem is i have a bunch on controllers doing AJAX request, and i don't want to be checking for `auth_error` in each one of them. I'm looking for a `don't repeat yourself` sort of solution, where my service holds the login info, and reacts to the changes made to that info

Comment: @ChrisHermut i guessed it myself, that's why i asked the question as to how would i do it from inside the service, without relying on $watch

Comment: Ah, so detecting the error is the problem. Use a $http interceptor (responseError): https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors. In the interceptor, check if the error is an auth error (normally, 401 status code), and if it is, call the logout() method of your service, which will set is_logged_in to false and redirect to the login route.

Comment: @JBNizet in that case too, i'll have to check of an additional case in each of my $http requests. That's not a solution

Comment: No. You'll have to check if the error is a 401 in the interceptor only.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to put that watcher in run phase on the angular application which will be there at a single place, by which you could check the value `is_logged_in` flag of service & if user is not login then redirect him/her to login page directily.

**Code**

```
app.run(function($rootScope, loginManager, $location){
   $rootScope.$watch(function(){
      return loginManager.is_logged_in;
   }, function(newValue){
       if(angular.isDefine(newValue) && !newValue)
         $location.path('/login');
         //$state.go('login'); //if you are using ui.router 
   })
})
```

**Edit**

Really curious part of your question is, from where you are changing `is_logged_in` flag of your service as @JBNizet asked? If any code is there is JavaScript then you should directly redirect to login page from there.

Comment: that was what i was looking for, in addition, [this post on role based authentication in angular js](http://arthur.gonigberg.com/2013/06/29/angularjs-role-based-auth/) is particularly what i was looking for

Comment: @IshanKhare may I know why you removed unvote & mark from answer?

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Pankaj Pakar's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34187987/4275217) answer could work but you should use angular's [interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) for that. They intercept all messages. You could add hook for response or responseError and when you recieve `auth_error` you do any action you like. For example `$location.path('/login')`, display error to user, etc.

If you want to separate logic you could inject your service with all code inside and just call some method on it.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the need to answer something more, Mior is quite right, but his answer needs more meat.

Here I show you how I managed to handle ALL server XHR requests with response 401 unauthorized.

First of all you need a service:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('theModule')
    .factory('interceptorService', ['$q', '$location', function ($q, $location) {
        return {
            response: function (response) {
                return response || $q.when(response);
            },
            responseError: function (rejection) {
                var returnTo = $location.path().replace(/^\/|\/$/g, '');
                if (returnTo === 'login') {
                    return;
                }
                if (rejection.status === 401) {
                    console.log('Unauthorized');
                    $location.path('/login').search('returnTo', returnTo);
                }
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    }]);
```

This will be used to intercept all XHR calls and to change the location every time a 401 error is found.

I've also added an improvement that is the "returnTo" parameter, you will be able to use it after login to return to the previous page.

To bind it to each request you have to call the config method, this is my main javascript.

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @author Gianmarco Laggia
 *
 * Main module of the application an configurations.
 */
angular
    .module('theModule', [])
    .config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
        //Http Interceptor to check auth failures for xhr requests
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('interceptorService');
    }]);
```

This is pretty much what you need to intercept every request, working on the rejection.status you can also intercept events such as server down (status is -1), internal server error (500+), success status (in the response part, status 200+) etc.